# How can I change numbering format in picker view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I am beginner in coding and would like to display only integers (1 , 2 , 3 , 4) 
in my `UIPickerView` rather than (0.0 , 0.1 , 0.3 , 0,4).

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld, %ld",(long)component,(long)row];
}
```

thanks

Comment: when i used the code you provided all pickers values turn to characters. i would like to only have the last section in the picker to display characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use this method:

```
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Apple provides great documentation for issues like this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html.

Comment: Dear ctapp1 thanks for your answer , and i have changed it from long to show. How can i reset the values in each column? to be like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 rather than 1.1 1.2 1.3 , then second section 2.1 2.2... your help please.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to return the row formatted to a string. Like so:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", row];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate , in the last section rather than displaying numbers how i can display characters (C D F G J K M Z)? you help please :D

Comment: thanks adam , when i used the code you provided all pickers values turn to characters. i would like to only have the last section in the picker to display characters. @adam

Comment: Then return different strings based off of the pickerView/componenet/whatever - I've given you the basics that you need to get the job done. Good luck!